# Wordpress Gutenberg Video, HTML, Embed Blocks custom place implementation

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I am working on a Wordpress Theme. I am a beginner with WordPress. Especially Gutenberg is hard to understand for me.

I want to add video with use Video block or Embed Block or HTML Block. My code is like this:

```
<?php if(has_block('video') || has_block('core-embed/youtube') || has_block('html')) : ?> 
    <?php
        **show video here**
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What code has to be used if the admin uses these 3 blocks for adding a video to the post ?

Comment: The thing is: a post may have none or all 3 types of blocks, and for each of them it doesn't necessarily has to be exactly one (can be 10 `video` blocks, as well). You will have to use `parse_blocks( $post->post_content )` to retrieve an array of blocks of your post. Then, you will have to check each entry's `blockName` property if it is either video, core-embed/youtube, or html. Depending on the structure of those blocks, you will have to get their content and output it where you want and apply necessary filters before.

Comment: Thank you for your attention,
According to my theme; every post can have only 1 video. The problem is; the admin who will use this theme how will add the video. There are 3 ways as i mentioned previous post, Video Block, Embed Block or HTML. If one of these 3 blocks had used by admin we will show the video in my place which i already defined before.